# VS2022 compiled exe closes upon startup on fresh system

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, software-distribution

We have been working on a project written in C++ for about half a year, and recently tried to run the finished product on a set of fresh systems. Some of the systems complained about missing the MSVCP140.dll libraries and likes and worked fine once those libraries were added onto those PCs, but most of them simply open and immediately closed our .exe file without any error messages.

We suspected those systems were also missing the libraries, but to our surprise they were already installed. We also tried installing the VC_redist64 packages on those PCs, but that didn't fix the problem either, leaving us with no idea what we're missing.

Sadly I cannot provide any more details, as we aren't given any errors to work from and lack the experience in actually providing programs for the end user, having only really done projects for college projects before now.

Edit: We have, via a new version of the set up/installer project, managed to get an output on a PC claiming that CreateDeviceAndSwapChain in DirectX11 failed an assert. We'll look into that and see if we manage to add DirectX to the installer and if that fixed the problem.

Comment: I always link to the static runtime libraries to avoid any external dependencies, it might be worth trying that (but it won't work if your exe is calling DLLs that link with the dynamic libraries).

Comment: *once those libraries were added onto those PCs* If you did not add these files by installing the runtime redistributable you may have opened yourself up to a world of hurt.

Comment: But wait! If you add DLLs from somewhere and install the runtime redistributable as well, that leads to [DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell), a place you most definitely don't want to be.

Comment: Meanwhile, in the Linux world, both dominant package managers, rpm/dnf and dpkg/apt, automatically record all shared library dependencies of properly built packages, with no manual action needed. And when the package gets installed on a system all required dependencies get automatically installed, if they're not already.

Comment: [VS2022 added some sanitizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/?view=msvc-170). Turn 'em on and see if they can spot anything wrong in the code that you're missing out on on your development computer. Undefined Behaviour can be a real <expletive deleted>.

Comment: You could use the [DebugView utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to try and diagnose the missing DLLs.

Comment: @PaulSanders, we did try doing that a while back (which I forgot to mention in the post, sorry about that), or at least I think we did. At the very least we changed from Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD) to Multi-Threaded (/MT) in the Code Generation properties, so I doubt that's the problem, even if it probably would cause problems in the future to not have it.

Comment: Time to drop to the low level debugger.  Run the executable under windbg and look at loader snap traces if needed

Comment: Also check if Event Viewer shows anything.

Comment: @user4581301 I enabled the address sanitizer, and it does give a lovely error when compiling "C1358 module (key=0x3297) information unavailable", which I have no idea what to make of really but at least we have an error to work from now.

Comment: I don't know that one either, but the sanitizer error reports come at runtime, not when building. Perhaps the error means it can't use the sanitizer. Maybe I'm giving you bad advice and the sanitizers are only implemented in the more expensive editions.

Comment: If the EXE opens and then disappears with no message, there's a chance that the OS dumped it. Have a look in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps` and see if you got lucky.

Comment: @paddy good plan, but sadly there weren't any crash dumps on any of the pcs.

Comment: Remember to always include your compilers runtime libraries in your installer.

Comment: @JesperJuhl we have managed to, via a new debug version the installer, narrow it down to it seemingly being DirectX not working as intended on the target PCs, as "CreateDeviceAndSwapChain" fails. So this might have morphed into a DirectX issue, though still related to redistribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have now resolved the issue. The installer had a couple of files missing, which would have caused issues and were found when running a debug version of the game via the installer.

This in turn led us to try sending a debug version of the game to the testers, which finally led us to the somewhat embarrassing revelation that we had missed removing the "D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG" flag from the release version of the game, causing the program to crash (without output in release mode) on non-developer PCs.

Removing this flag has resolved the issue and enables us to redistribute the game seemingly without issue.